# How to get filename from Oracle Directory from PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have created an Oracle Directory on my local computer (c:\temp),
and as an example I also put several files inside that directory:

- word.docx
- excel.xls
- pic.jpeg
- pdf.pdf

My question is how I can get all the filenames inside that directory from PL/SQL?

Thank you

Comment: Oracle Directories are pointers to a location on Physical drive. Don't think there is any proc in Oracle 11g to read the contents of the physical directory. All its procedures and functions work on a particular file

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  PL/SQL doesn't provide a function to list the contents of a directory.

Assuming that the Oracle database is installed on your local server (the database generally cannot access files stored on the client file system) you can, however, create a [Java stored procedure that lists the contents of an operating system directory](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:439619916584) and call that from PL/SQL.  The thread I links to provides one implementation of this sort of procedure.  There are other implementations floating around on the internet as well.

Comment: I tried the link you gave, but when I tried to execute it, it has error

SQL> exec get_dir_list('c:\temp\');
 
begin get_dir_list('c:\ccint\'); end;
 
ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
ORA-06512: at "I.GET_DIR_LIST", line 1
ORA-06512: at line 2

Do you happen to know what when wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I would guess that either the directory doesn't exist (the directory in your `exec` doesn't match the directory in the anonymous PL/SQL block SQL*Plus constructed which isn't possible-- you must have edited something before posting) or that you didn't grant the privileges that Tom outlined.  If you're convinced that you're having problems, edit your question to post an example that shows us every step you are performing.  Ideally, you'd post something exactly like what Tom posted https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:439619916584#3774655970547

Comment: Try leaving off the trailing backslash on 'C:\temp\' in your call to get_dir_list.

Comment: Hi Cave, thank you so much for your answers, I already manage to find what went wrong and the link you gave, it does work.